# exec() and root user in PHP

Tags: php, linux, security, sudo, su

I'm building a control panel in PHP.
This CP will manage Linux users, their screen sessions and files.

I want to list all approaches and choose the most secure way which will be comfortable for user too.

## Broad sudoers file (VERY dangerous!)

/etc/sudoers

```
wwwuser ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This allows any command to be run via www server user.
It's security nightmare.

#### Pros

- All commands are available

#### Cons

- All commands are available

## Wrapper scripts

/etc/sudoers

```
wwwuser ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/scripts/scripts/
```

This method uses small bash scripts with only few lines. Unfortunately those scripts must take arguments increasing attack surface.
For example this script create new user

`#/bin/bash
useradd $1 -s /bin/bash`

I can't list all allowed usernames so I must use args.

#### Pros

- Only whitelisted commands are allowed if script is called with escapeshellarg()
- Gives elasticity for created usernames, folders etc.

#### Cons

- Modifying arguments via enduser is imposible eg. for running java applications in screen.

## Queue running as root user

In this method all commands that need root rights, are sent to queue.
Queue daemon runs as root so it can create users etc.

#### Pros

- Lower attack surface than allowing wwwuser to run any command
- Elastic arguments to run or filenames to create are no longer a problem

#### Cons

- Security is mostly dependent on application itself

Comment: I would use the [PAM module](https://pecl.php.net/package/PAM) instead. Once you've configured PAM to allow PHP to access it, you could use the current Linux accounts as login accounts to your control panel and build on that. Another (perhaps even better) solution would be to use LDAP.

Comment: @icecub I like a idea to integrate with OS accounts, but how to run cmds from PAM logged user if page runs as wwwuser?

Comment: There are a couple of solutions for that. To name a few: [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/suexec.html) or [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html). They allow you to run PHP scripts as a different user.

Comment: @icecub for performance reasons I use nginx + php-fpm.
suEXEC and suPHP are solutions only for Apache IIRC.
It will be hard or impossible to run php-fpm pool and nginx worker for each user.

Comment: Hmm. Well my Linux knowledge is to limited to give a perfect solution for that. However, you could go for LDAP instead. Setting it up correctly will probebly be a huge challange. But the benefits will be amazing! It'll allow you to connect pretty much any OS and programming language together setting up rights perfectly.